# is there a way to add custom variables to product description (using the editor) in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.2, wysiwyg, variables, custom-variable

I am using magento 2.2.2 and I want to add custom variables to the products description.

for now, I can do that with the pages but not for the products (in the page editor there's a button called "insert variable" and it will insert a variable, (e.g: `{{customVar code=variable_here}}`)

but if I tried that in a product description, it doesn't work.

any suggestions?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this from your own module by defining a plugin. Note that the following solution is a workaround.

a) You can define a plugin in etc/frontend/di.xml as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output">
        <plugin name="variable" type="Test\Variable\Plugin\Output" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

b) Plugin would then define an afterProductAttribute() as follows

```
namespace Test\Variable\Plugin;

class Output

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider
     */
    protected $filterProvider;

    /**
     * Constructor 
     * 
     * @param \Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider $filterProvider
     */
    public function __construct
    (
        \Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider $filterProvider
    )
    {
        $this->filterProvider = $filterProvider;
    }

    /**
     * Filter outpout of value 
     * 
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output $context
     * @param mixed $value
     * @return string
     */
    public function afterProductAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output $context, $value)
    {
        return $this->filterProvider->getBlockFilter()->filter($value);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.